# $(a+b\sqrt{2})^n =(c+d\sqrt{3})^m =>ab=cd=0$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a,b,c,d \in Q, m,n \in N^*$ and $(a+b\sqrt{2})^n =(c+d\sqrt{3})^m$ then to show that
$ab=cd=0$.

An idea to solve it by contradiction but ...

Comment: That can't be true. In particular, $a = c$, $b = d$, $n = m$ *always* is a solution, so taking $a = c = 1$, $b = d =1 $, $n = m = 1$ gives a counterexample.

Comment: @Feanor Notice that the surds are different, so you don't have a valid counterexample.

Comment: Yes, apologies for the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $AB\neq0$.

**Hint:** $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] \cap \mathbb{Q} [\sqrt{3}] = \mathbb{Q}$.

> This tells us that $(a+b\sqrt{2})^n = p \in \mathbb{Q}$.

**Hint:** Consider conjugates.

> Taking the conjugates, we get that $(a-b\sqrt{2})^n = p$. Taking the difference, we get that $ 2b \sum {n \choose 2i} a^{n-2i}b^{i}2^i = 0$.

If $n$ is even, we have a non-zero ($2b$) multiplied by a (positive) sum of squares, which can't be 0. This is a contradiction.

> If $n$ is odd, we have $2ab \sum{n \choose 2i} a^{n-2i-1} b^i 2^i = 0 $. Once again, we have a non-zero ($2ab$) multiplied by a (positive) sum of squares, which can't be 0. This is a contradiction.

Hence, $AB=0$. Similarly, $CD=0$.